# Moving Coupon Block on the top of the page

Tags: magento2

I would like to move coupon block on the upper side of the page (before cart summary).

Coupon block are located on: **App/design/frontend/mytheme/themename/default/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.container">
        <container name="cart.discount" label="Cart Discount Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="cart-discount" after="-" />
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="checkout.cart.crosssell" destination="checkout.cart.container" after="-" />
    <move element="checkout.cart.coupon" destination="cart.discount" />
    <move element="checkout.cart.shortcut.buttons" destination="checkout.cart.methods" after="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom"/>
</body>
```

Comment: you can try this or follow this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219518/magento-2-i-need-to-move-coupon-form-in-checkout-page-to-the-page-top <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body> <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.coupon" remove="true"/> <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon2" as="coupon" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/coupon.phtml"/> <move element="checkout.cart.coupon2" destination="cart.summary"

Comment: you can follow this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219518/magento-2-i-need-to-move-coupon-form-in-checkout-page-to-the-page-top and as wall this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249967/apply-discount-block-moving-issue-in-magento2-cart-page